# Move game objects on the another game object Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, chess, gameobject

I have this scene in unity with a chessboard and pieces. Each figure and chessboard are models downloaded from asset store. So I want the user to click on the square and click on the figure to move my figure to this square on the chessboard. How can I do this with my game object? Should I define some coordinates of squares clicked by the user? And how can I track where the user clicked?

My scene looks like this:
[image]

I had only such scripts for moving figures to defined by me square. An example for a rook:

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z + 71);
}
```

Comment: there are plenty of ways to archieve this, what probably helps the most is to set your chessboard up in a way where its easy for you to calculate coordinates, like f.e having the center of A0 sit on the world origin and the indivdual fields an size of (1, 1). then you can just raycast against either a collider or a plane and get the individual field coordinates by rounding to the next integer (`Mathf.RoundToInt(float, float)`). ofc you can also have arbitrary sizes, its just a tiny bit more complicated to calculate (but totally doable with very basic math)

Comment: In terms of your game loop, I'd suggest you have the player select the piece to move first, then select a square to move it to. Aside from this being more akin to how you play chess in real life, you'll also have the capability to show available moves for the selected piece (based on its movement rules and other pieces around it).

Comment: @Serlite nice idea! How can I suggest the user possible moves? I mean is there a way to change color or some lighting for squares?

Comment: @Cassie I'm not familiar with your scene setup, but if tinting the material of the square doesn't work, you could try swapping out the texture for each relevant square instead, so they look highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than defining some grid, or rounding to nearest integers, you could simply have a collider on every square.

Each of those squares would be part of a square collision layer. Then you would do the same for all the pieces, allowing for the peice layer to interact with the square layer (so they don't fall through the table)

Then comes the easy part: You just do two raycasts, the first against pieces, to determine what piece the user is trying to move, and the second to determine where they are trying to move it (and move the piece to the center of the square)

[This question](https://answers.unity.com/questions/332085/how-do-you-make-an-object-respond-to-a-click-in-c.html) also might be of some use in figuring out how to select objects.